# How to configure Eclipse's language server to include additional source directories such `target/generated-sources`?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, neovim

The story behind the question is that I have a Spring-Graphql project where the GraphQL entities are generated by [this](https://github.com/kobylynskyi/graphql-java-codegen) plugin, and the generated code is placed under `${project.dir}/target/generated-sources`. IntelliJ sees the directory by default, but NeoVim and Eclipse don't, so they could not parse the classes there and the whole code on the screen is just red.

I read in the interwebs that I need `build-helper-maven-plugin` and configured like below.

When I open java files with NeoVim (which uses Eclipse's lang server for intellisense and other magic) the situation is still the same. When I check what `.classpath` is generated by the language server in the porject root I see that `target/generated-sources` directory are not listed there. Meaning I either configured badly the plugin (it compiles and runs tests as expected) badly or there is a disagreement between Eclipse and Maven configuration manifesting in what I described above.

What configuration is needed for NeoVim (it will be jdtls setup, and eventually Eclipse lang server config) to see the generated sources directory?

[Here](https://github.com/Andras-Csanyi/so_examples/tree/main/include_sources_directory) is an example project demonstrating the problem.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${basedir}/target/generated-sources</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

`.classpath` file generated by Eclipse's Language server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="target/generated-sources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-11">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="ignore_optional_problems" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="m2e-apt" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: `.classpath` contains `<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="target/generated-sources">` which looks fine. Which errors do you get exactly where? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @howlger you are right. It is there. Then the case is more head scratching. I'll put together an example and put the link into the description.

Comment: Added the example

Answer (score 0):

The solution is further specify the included directory like below.
This way the language server can pick it up and see what is there and NeoVim works just fine.

The easiest way to experiment with these using Eclipse. If the mvn setup works there highly probably will work wiht NeoVim hence they use the same language server.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/graphql/</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```